# Select a tag element inside a another element selected by class JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code and is working

```
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
        for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
        myClasses[i].innerHTML = "<img src='http://url.com/image'>";
        }
```

But I need select a  element iside myClass element.
How can i do this with js?

Thank you!

My html is something like that:

```
<div class="myClass">
        <span>Span</span>
        <a href="link" rel="nofollow">Content to replace with img</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what element you want to select?

Comment: i have this html: `<div class="myClass" >    
         <a href="link" rel="nofollow"> Content to replace</a>
     </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()`

```js
var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass a");
for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
  myClasses[i].innerHTML = "<img src='http://url.com/image'>";
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <span>Span</span>
  <a href="link" rel="nofollow">Content to replace with img</a>
</div>
```

Comment: but if want to select a tag element without class? For example the div inside the div myClass

Comment: You can still use `querySelector` but can you post your html.

Comment: and for select multiple items in the same script? For example "myClass a" and "myClass2" a

Comment: You would need attr selector `starts with` for that https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/802/. This selects every div that has class that starts with `myClass`

Comment: I haven't explained well. One class is "myClass" but the other class is "another". Thank you

Comment: If those divs have nothing in common then you need to select them separately https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/804/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE8, you can do it in this way:

`document.querySelector('.myClass TAGNAME');`
or, if you want select all elements:
`document.querySelectorAll('.myClass TAGNAME');`